# IPv6 RAs on Cisco 4500 switch

Tags: cisco, ipv6, lan

In a LAN only network without any routers but only two levels of switchs (4500s for core and  2960s for access) I would like to enable IPv6 autoconfiguration for Windows 7 hosts.

Is it possible for the 4500s to send RAs with a prefix and thus allow hosts for stateless conf ?

I am not sure wether it is relevant or not but the LAN is divided between VLANs for which each of the switchs has a configured IPv6.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are talking about the 3750 or the 2960 you mention above. But yes IPv6 stateless autoconfiguration on interfaces, subnets and sites is supported by both switches with the minimum IOS 12.2(44)SE.

Comment: Sorry, I was speaking of the 4500 (I edited the question above...). Ok, then I should be able to make it work.
But to complete my question and check that we are speaking of the same thing: I would like that the 4500 sends RAs containing the prefix of the IPv6 defined on each VLANs. I have the feeling that you are speaking of the autoconfiguration from the hosts point of view.

Comment: Gotcha. With the early hour here in san jose and the fact I haven't had my second cup of coffee at the time, I wasn't sure what you were asking lol. But yeah, should work fine. Just make sure you configure the RA from the actual VLAN interface, you can then advertise which prefix you want. 


(config) #interface vlan 300
        
(config-subif)#ipv6 address xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        
(config-subif)#ipv6 nd ra enable
        
(config-subif)#ipv6 nd ra prefix X:X:X:X::X/64

Comment: Hi, i am testing this on a 4506 with 12.2 54 SG, but some commands are not available (ipv6 nd ra enable for instance). Also i don't have access to ipv6 command on physical interface... Any idea where that can come from ? Thanks